# AheadWorks - Follow Up Email extension review event

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates, review

I'm using Follow Up Email extension from AheadWorks.
I wrote a rule to send a notification email when a user has submitted a review.
What I'd want to achieve is to state name and sku of product for which review has been submitted.
Unfortunately
    `{{var product.getName()}}`
and
    `{{var product.getSku()}}`
do not work.
So I'm wondering if it's possible to get the product related to review in template variables.

Comment: you need to set those variable from code, then you need to use these variables to template.